# Error while trying to list folders inside a GCP organisation

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, grpc, grpc-go

I'm trying to write a simple code in GO that lists all the folders under an organisation in GCP using the [resourcemanager](https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/resourcemanager/latest/apiv2#example_5) API. Below is my code:

```
package main

import (
   "context"
   "log"

   resourcemanager "cloud.google.com/go/resourcemanager/apiv2"
   "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
   resourcemanagerpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/resourcemanager/v2"
)

func main() {
   ctx := context.Background()
   c, err := resourcemanager.NewFoldersClient(ctx)
   if err != nil {
       // TODO: Handle error.
       log.Println("Error: Failed to start client.")
   }
   defer c.Close()

   req := &resourcemanagerpb.ListFoldersRequest{
       Parent: "organizations/<MY-ORG-NAME>",
   }

   it := c.ListFolders(ctx, req)

   tries := 0

   for {
       resp, err := it.Next()
       if err == iterator.Done || tries == 3 {
           break
       }
       if err != nil {
          log.Println(err)
       }
       // TODO: Use resp.
       log.Println(resp)
       tries++
   }
}
```

The code is directly copied from the API documentation, I just added my organisation name, added some log features and limited the tries in the for loop, since it was endlessly printing errors.

I'm getting the following error messages whenever I run the code:

```
2021/11/04 17:06:41 rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 404 (Not Found); transport: received unexpected content-type "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

I'm not sure if this is the solution but; I think I need to add a `.proto` file in my directory for it to work, but I didn't understand how to do that or what exactly to put in there. I'm new to GO and it's my first time working with API's so this all seems very confusing to me.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you are properly authorized, e.g. by providing a service account key via GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS .

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Volker!

I'm not sure that's necessary, it says on the documentation that the client uses the default credentials on my local machine, the credentials that I get when I run `gcloud auth login`

Comment: Google [APIs Explorer] is useful for debugging this type of issue. The underlying request is [folders.list](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v2/folders/list). Can you try to repro the request using "Try this API" there? If that works, we know it's the code. I don't use Orgs and Folders so it's challenging for me to try to repro this.

Comment: No, you don't need protos. You are using code generated from protos and it should work (and should communicate using the message formats defined in the protos from which it was sourced).

Comment: @DazWilkin I didn't know about the API explorer, it seems so useful!
I tried the `"organizations/ORG-ID"` string there and it worked.

So, judging by the error message my code gives me, maybe the way I pass the `parent` string is wrong, or not syntaxed in a way the function expects it?

Comment: The `Parent` stuff is gnarly with Google's APIs but, what you have is correct. If you're using the same value in APIs Explorer (which works) as in your code, you should be good.

Comment: I'm assuming the error is in `c.ListFolders` rather than `it.Next()`. Is that correct? Please include the full stacktrace. Be mindful of redacting any personal info.

Comment: I omitted to include the URL for [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) previously. It's a very useful tool. Every Google (not just Cloud Platform) API is included. It documents the request|response messages and the majority can be tested using it.

Comment: I've a sneaking suspicion, the error is in the iterator; I've a feeling Google change(broke) it recently.

Comment: To @volker comment, you will need to either [`gcloud auth application-default log`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) to acquire ADCs for use with your regular (user) account. Alternatively, you can create a Service Account but that should (!) not be necessary. I would suspect if that weren't working correctly though, you'd get the equivalent of a 403 (Forbidden) rather than 404 but let's see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating to the API v3 solved the problem. This works perfectly!

Thank you to everyone who commented and to my coworker who found the solution!

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    cloudresourcemanager "google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v3"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    svc, err := cloudresourcemanager.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    foldersService := cloudresourcemanager.NewFoldersService(svc)
    foldersListCall := foldersService.List()
    foldersListCall.Parent("organizations/<MY-ORG-ID>")
    resp, err := foldersListCall.Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, fld := range resp.Folders {
        fmt.Println(fld.DisplayName)
    }
}
```